# twig рендеринг текущей - открытой страницы(решение)

Tags: php, twig

Столкнулся с задачей рендеринга открытой(текущей) страницы сайта. Т.е. сначала документ открывается, на нем выполняется код php, и только потом происходит рендеринг. 
Решение простое, но в интернете я его не нашел. Поэтому и создаю данную "тему".
Решение полностью на php, без использования js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня все подключения и файлы работают через корневой index.php. У вас может быть реализовано иначе, поэтому будьте внимательны. 
В самом начале страницы включаем буфер обмена:

```
ob_start();
```

После чего инклюдим необходимые файлы, или просто выводим html - всё зависит от вашей ситуации. 
После всего вывода контента, в самом конце пишем сам рендеринг:

```
$listdatainfoall = ob_get_clean(); 
echo $twig->render(twig_template_from_string($twig,$listdatainfoall,'test'), $data_array_from_zamena);
```

twig_template_from_string - в интернете чаще всего используется другая функция, а именно template_from_string. Однако, даже после подключения дополнения, она у меня так и оказалась неизвестной функцией. Подглядел в код вызываемой функции - и наткнулся на twig_template_from_string, которая прописана в подключаемом файле. Она "создаёт" шаблон из строкового значения. Ну а после, мы выполняем рендеринг, заменяя {{данные}} на данные из массива $data_array_from_zamena.
Полный код: 
1) Подключение

```
ob_start();    
$loader = new \Twig\Loader\FilesystemLoader(SITE_CAT);
        $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader, [
            'cache' => SITE_CACHE,
        ]);
    $twig->addExtension(new \Twig\Extension\StringLoaderExtension());
```

2) HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
    Текст {{ data }}
</body>
</html>
```

3) ну и рендеринг

```
$listdatainfoall = ob_get_clean(); 
echo $twig->render(twig_template_from_string($twig,$listdatainfoall,'test'), $data_array_from_zamena);
```

Как то так.